# Joint distribution of two normal random variables

Tags: normal-distribution

Let
\begin{align}
    &x \sim p_x = N(\mu_x, \sigma_x^2) \\
    &u \sim p_u = N(\mu_u, \sigma_u^2) \text{ is independent of x}\\
    &y = x + u 
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
    &y \sim p_y = N(\mu_x + \mu_u, \sigma_x^2 + \sigma_u^2) 
\end{align}
How to find $p(y|x)$?
As far as I understand, to solve the problem, it is necessary to find the density of the joint distribution, but I do not understand how to construct a joint distribution function in this case.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I added some of my thoughts.